# Zeroing a value on the device vs doing it from the host and transferring to device

Tags: vulkan, compute-shader

I need to conditionally write to a storage buffer in the fragment shader, but before the fragment shader runs I have to make the data in the buffer null, so that I know if the fragment shader wrote to it or not. First I thought I could do it by writing the null value from the host, and transferring it to the device-local buffer. But then I thought is there a way for the device to make it null itself? Can I run a compute operation to set it to null? Is this a better solution? What would I set the workgroup sizes to if I just have to write one value?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [vkCmdFillBuffer](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#vkCmdFillBuffer).